# Order segment of array by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Can u help me please create a function which change order part of array by property.

Example:

```
 const input = [
    {firstName: 'Jack1', lastName: 'Snow1'},
    {firstName: 'Jack2', lastName: 'Snow2'},
    {firstName: 'Jack3', lastName: 'Snow3'},
    {firstName: 'Jack4', lastName: 'Snow4'},
    {firstName: 'Jack5', lastName: 'Snow5'},
];

const order = ['Jack3', 'Jack2', 'Jack4'];


function orderBySegment(input, order, 'firstName') {

}

const output = [
  {firstName: 'Jack3', lastName: 'Snow3'},
  {firstName: 'Jack2', lastName: 'Snow2'},
  {firstName: 'Jack4', lastName: 'Snow4'},
  {firstName: 'Jack1', lastName: 'Snow1'},
  {firstName: 'Jack5', lastName: 'Snow5'},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
    {firstName: 'Jack1', lastName: 'Snow1'},
    {firstName: 'Jack2', lastName: 'Snow2'},
    {firstName: 'Jack3', lastName: 'Snow3'},
    {firstName: 'Jack4', lastName: 'Snow4'},
    {firstName: 'Jack5', lastName: 'Snow5'},
];

const order = ['Jack3', 'Jack2', 'Jack4'];


function orderBySegment(input, order, key) {
  return input.sort((a, b) => {
    const aValue = a[key], bValue = b[key];
    const aIndex = order.indexOf(aValue), bIndex = order.indexOf(bValue);
    if (aIndex === -1)
      return 1;
    else if (bIndex === -1)
      return -1;
    else 
      return aIndex - bIndex;
  });
}

console.log(orderBySegment(input, order, 'firstName'));
```